# How to configure the DotNet SDK used by FSAC –or– DLL Hell on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, dll, f#, .net-core, code-completion

I'm learning F#, never having used any DotNet nor Mono before. I like the language, but I'm having a hard time with the myriad runtime versions and how to tell the various tools which version to use.

**Summary:** it appears DLL Hell on Ubuntu is a thing. How can I tell [FSAC](https://github.com/fsharp/FsAutoComplete) to run its auto-complete magic against the latest runtime version, namely Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.5, instead of whatever older incarnation it decided to use?

---

Longish explanation.

My platform is Ubuntu 18.04 amd64. I have installed the latest DotNet Core, specifically the packages `dotnet-sdk-2.1` (version `2.1.403-1`) and its dependencies `dotnet-host`, `dotnet-runtime-2.1`, etc. (which are all version `2.1.5-1`). I also have Mono installed, because many tools apparently rely on it.

When I try to use some features that were recently added to DotNet Core, it feels like I'm uncovering a Pandora Box.

Take this example, which uses the new `ProcessStartInfo.ArgumentList`:

```
#r "System.Diagnostics.Process.dll"

open System.Diagnostics

let execute exe args =
    let proc = new Process()
    proc.StartInfo.FileName <- exe
    for arg in args do proc.StartInfo.ArgumentList.Add arg
    proc.Start() |> ignore
    proc.WaitForExit()

execute "echo" ["foo"; "baz"]
```

If I naively try to run it with `/usr/bin/fsharpi` (which exec's `/usr/bin/mono /usr/lib/mono/fsharp/fsi.exe`) I get a "ArgumentList is not defined" error. Fair enough, I guess?

If I run it with `/usr/bin/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.403/FSharp/fsi.exe` **it works!** It took me a long time to figure out I could even do it, but at last I'm on the right path.

But if I load the file in any IDE, such as VSCode with the Ionide plugin, or Sublime Text with the FSharp plugin, they still flag `ArgumentList` as invalid. Sublime's plugin also flags the `#r` line as invalid, but doesn't tell me why.

Focusing on Sublime's plugin and digging into the code, it appears that it relies on a tool called [FsAutoComplete aka. fsac](https://github.com/fsharp/FsAutoComplete) and on Linux [explicitly invokes it with mono](https://github.com/fsharp/sublime-fsharp-package/blob/e8f29405b5ad1d452bc556ab4742fc9d9e84776b/src/fsac/server.py#L153).

I tried running the FSAC tool with DotNet Core, but it fails to find some library or other:

```
$ cd .config/sublime-text-3/Packages/FSharp/fsac/fsac/
$ dotnet fsautocomplete.exe 
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/home/tobia/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/FSharp/fsac/fsac/'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app. If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the /home/tobia/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/FSharp/fsac/fsac/fsautocomplete.runtimeconfig.json file specifying the appropriate framework.
```

If I take a filesystem approach and search for `System.Diagnostics.Process.dll`, I'm baffled by the results:

```
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions/net461/lib/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.403/Microsoft/Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions/net461/lib/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/netstandard.library/2.0.3/build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.diagnostics.process/4.3.0/lib/net46/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.diagnostics.process/4.3.0/lib/net461/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.diagnostics.process/4.3.0/ref/net46/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.diagnostics.process/4.3.0/ref/net461/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.diagnostics.process/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.diagnostics.process/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.4/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.diagnostics.process/4.3.0/runtimes/linux/lib/netstandard1.4/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.diagnostics.process/4.3.0/runtimes/osx/lib/netstandard1.4/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.diagnostics.process/4.3.0/runtimes/win/lib/net46/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.diagnostics.process/4.3.0/runtimes/win/lib/net461/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.diagnostics.process/4.3.0/runtimes/win/lib/netstandard1.4/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.5/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
```

Plus another dozen in my home directory, under `~/.nuget`. That's insane.

To begin with, the entire `/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder` subtree **does not seem to be owned by any Deb package,** which is worrisome enough. The others belong to these packages:

```
    mono-devel:         /usr/lib/mono/4.5/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
    mono-devel:         /usr/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
    msbuild:            /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions/net461/lib/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
    dotnet-sdk-2.1:     /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.403/Microsoft/Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions/net461/lib/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
(*) dotnet-runtime-2.1: /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.5/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
```

Running a simple Grep shows that only the last one marked with `(*)` knows anything about `ArgumentList`.

**So all these other libraries are older / legacy versions,** including the one in `dotnet-sdk-2.1` itself.

I can only presume that the SDK, aka. the compilers and interpreters, are built against an older version of the runtime / system libraries than the one they build code against. Which is an interesting choice, to say the least.

---

Taking a process approach, `lsof` tells me that the FSAC process has only opened DLL files from inside `/usr/lib/mono` and from its own local directory. This is not promising.

Is there a way to tell FSAC to use the Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.5 runtime / system libraries for its autocomplete and linting work?

Comment: I don't think FSI can use dotnetcore. You can build against it but in fsharp interactive you would need to rely on mono if on Linux. VSCode has an option to use dotnetcore fsac, take a look at the F# related settings.

Comment: @s952163 I'm using dotnetcore's FSI already. (It was buried somewhere in my long rant: `dotnet /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.403/FSharp/fsi.exe`) They're still working on line editing support, but everything else seems to work so far. As for VSCode, I thought I had enabled all the dotnetcore options I could find and it still wasn't recognizing ArgumentList. I'll look into its plugin source code next.